# How to convert Mesh thickness into Colour node?

Tags: materials

do you have any clue how to create Mesh thickness colour node?
 I just want to create material based on  mesh thcikness
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Haha. Found it! Apparantly Ambient Occlusion from inside measures the thickness colour of the mesh! 
[image]